# Mailchimp API - subscribe emails to a user's list

Tags: api, email, mailchimp

After reading through Mailchimps I could not find a definite answer...
Is it possible to use Mailchimp's API to subscribe emails to a user's account, and not my own?

I imagine this would work like so:

1. A user of my web app grants access to their MailChimp account
2. My webapp can then add email to the user's email lists

Answer (score 0):

When using the API you need the API key and credentials to access your account. If someone else shares their credentials with you, there is nothing stopping you API-ing into their account.

In other words, once you have permission, there is nothing you can do in the API on your own account, that you couldn't do to a different account.

Answer (score 0):

In short, yes it's possible.

All you'll need is the API key supplied by the user. You'll then use the API to create a list and use the that list's "list_id" in conjunction with the API key to add subscribers to the list created.

I'm busy working on adding users to a pre-existing list. I'm stuck on adding the API key to my call to Mailchimp but you may want to follow [my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30481979/adding-subscribers-to-a-list-using-mailchimps-api-v3) in the event I find an answer to it.