# Adding subscribers to a list using Mailchimp's API v3

Tags: php, json, curl, mailchimp, mailchimp-api-v3.0

I'm trying to add users to a list I've created in Mailchimp but I can't find any code examples anywhere. I've tried figuring out how to use the API but I'm very much a "Look at an example and learn" kind of person.

I've tried using version 2 of the API but nothing seems to be working despite working from examples on the net and Mailchimp says the following about earlier versions of their API on their website:

> Versions 2.0 and earlier are deprecated. Only minimal support—bug fixes, security patches—will be available for those versions.

**UPDATE 1**: I did some further research based on TooMuchPete's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30492435/2443113) with regards to the link on Managing Subscribers and altered some code I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2445332/2443113), but it won't work because the function [http_build_query()](https://php.net/http_build_query) doesn't deal with nested arrays. I'm not sure how to deal with the 'merge_fields' portion of adding a subscriber. My current code is below:

```
$postdata = http_build_query(
                    array(
                        'apikey'        => $apikey,
                        'email_address' => $email,
                        'status'        => 'subscribed',
                        'merge_fields'  => array(
                            'FNAME' => $name
                        )
                    )
                );

                $opts = array('http' =>
                    array(
                        'method'  => 'POST',
                        'header'  => 'Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                        'content' => $postdata
                    )
                );

                $context  = stream_context_create($opts);

                $result = file_get_contents('https://us2.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/lists/<list_id>/members/', false, $context);

                var_dump($result);
                die('Mailchimp executed');
```

**UPDATE 2**: I've now resorted to using curl and I've managed to get something almost working. The data sends through to Mailchimp but I'm receiving the error ***"Your request did not include an API key."*** I'm guessing I need to authenticate as mentioned [here](http://kb.mailchimp.com/api/article/api-3-overview). I've tried adding it to the http header which hasn't worked. See my code below:

```
$apikey = '<api_key>';
                $auth = base64_encode( 'user:'.$apikey );

                $data = array(
                    'apikey'        => $apikey,
                    'email_address' => $email,
                    'status'        => 'subscribed',
                    'merge_fields'  => array(
                        'FNAME' => $name
                    )
                );
                $json_data = json_encode($data);

                $ch = curl_init();
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://us2.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/lists/<list_id>/members/');
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json/r/n
                                                            Authorization: Basic '.$auth));
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'PHP-MCAPI/2.0');
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $json_data);                                                                                                                  

                $result = curl_exec($ch);

                var_dump($result);
                die('Mailchimp executed');
```

Comment: v2.0 still definitely works. v1.3 does, too, actually -- but if you're looking for API v3.0 examples, I'd check out this [GitHub repo](https://github.com/mailchimp/APIv3-examples). It only has Python right now, but that might be enough to get you pointed in the right direction in your language. There's also a page in the docs on [managing subscribers](http://kb.mailchimp.com/api/article/how-to-manage-subscribers), which is a step away from actual code examples, but might still be helpful.

Comment: Thanks @TooMuchPete. I updated my question with a code sample. I think I'm getting there slowly.

Comment: I'm looking for API v3.0 examples in python that aren't just basic get requests. The examples in that GitHub repo are lame, sorry.

Comment: GET requests and POST requests are not substantially different. One has a body, one doesn't. Combined with the [Python Requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) docs, I'm not sure what else someone would need to get started. The examples are definitely not for folks looking for copy and paste solutions or libraries, though.

Comment: MailChimp currently say they won't support versions prior to 3.0 beyond 2016.

Answer (score 136, accepted):

Based on the [List Members Instance docs](http://kb.mailchimp.com/api/resources/lists/members/lists-members-instance), the easiest way is to use a **`PUT`** request which according to the docs either *"adds a new list member or updates the member if the email already exists on the list"*.

Furthermore `apikey` is definitely not part of the [json schema](https://us9.api.mailchimp.com/schema/3.0/Lists/Members/Instance.json) and there's no point in including it in your json request.

Also, as noted in @TooMuchPete's comment, you can use `CURLOPT_USERPWD` for basic http auth as illustrated in below.

I'm using the following function to add and update list members.  You may need to include a slightly different set of `merge_fields` depending on your list parameters.

```
$data = [
    'email'     => 'johndoe@example.com',
    'status'    => 'subscribed',
    'firstname' => 'john',
    'lastname'  => 'doe'
];

syncMailchimp($data);

function syncMailchimp($data) {
    $apiKey = 'your api key';
    $listId = 'your list id';

    $memberId = md5(strtolower($data['email']));
    $dataCenter = substr($apiKey,strpos($apiKey,'-')+1);
    $url = 'https://' . $dataCenter . '.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/lists/' . $listId . '/members/' . $memberId;

    $json = json_encode([
        'email_address' => $data['email'],
        'status'        => $data['status'], // "subscribed","unsubscribed","cleaned","pending"
        'merge_fields'  => [
            'FNAME'     => $data['firstname'],
            'LNAME'     => $data['lastname']
        ]
    ]);

    $ch = curl_init($url);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, 'user:' . $apiKey);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, ['Content-Type: application/json']);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'PUT');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $json);                                                                                                                 

    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    $httpCode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
    curl_close($ch);

    return $httpCode;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this @billynoah. I merely accepted my own answer because it's what I managed to get working and no one else provided a working example.

Comment: Well, you can still use `POST`, but on a different endpoint (no ID). From the API docs:  `Create a new record with either a POST request to /lists/{list_id}/members or a PUT request to /lists/{list_id}/members/{id}. Remove a record with a DELETE request to /lists/{list_id}/members/{id}.`

Comment: Thanks @Aborted, didn't notice that bit.  Seems like they should include `POST` in the "HTTP Verbs Available" section at the beginning of that page.  I had tried sending post with the id included and was getting an error response - now I know why.

Comment: Can anyone tell me what to add/do to subscribe a mail directly into a group?

Comment: @ToniMichelCaubet - The docs don't offer any method to update or add multiple members at once to my knowledge.  I think you'd have to send a single request for each member to be added / edited.

Comment: If you get a 404 (The requested resource could not be found) you probably use a wrong list id (keep in mind its not the one in browser url but contains letters and numbers). If you get a 400 you should check your data array. Maybe the status field doesn't contain the strings?

Comment: I don't know why this isn't working for me.  Response comes back blank and nothing is added to the list.

Comment: @billynoah, any idea why I would get `404` file not found error? I've verified the set `api key` and `list id` multiple times and they are 100% ok, I've remained with no things to check. Can you please help me with this?

Comment: The only thing I can think and saw was that `$memberId` from the url endpoint will break the execution.

Comment: Can you post an example of the value of `$url` when you get a 404?

Comment: Please note this array syntax requires PHP >= 5.4

Comment: You could maybe also get a 404 error when the user already exists. The members endpoint does return that for an existing user. See https://mailchimp.com/developer/guides/manage-subscribers-with-the-mailchimp-api/.

Comment: @Remi - To my knowledge, there is *no situation* where you will get a 404 with a **put** request.

Answer (score 26):

I got it working. I was adding the authentication to the header incorrectly:

```
$apikey = '<api_key>';
            $auth = base64_encode( 'user:'.$apikey );

            $data = array(
                'apikey'        => $apikey,
                'email_address' => $email,
                'status'        => 'subscribed',
                'merge_fields'  => array(
                    'FNAME' => $name
                )
            );
            $json_data = json_encode($data);

            $ch = curl_init();
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://us2.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/lists/<list_id>/members/');
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json',
                                                        'Authorization: Basic '.$auth));
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'PHP-MCAPI/2.0');
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $json_data);                                                                                                                  

            $result = curl_exec($ch);

            var_dump($result);
            die('Mailchimp executed');
```

Comment: Cool! You can also do auth like this: `url_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "user:" . $apikey);`

Comment: Does that base64_encode it? Mailchimp requires that be encoded.

Comment: MailChimp API v3.0 uses HTTP Basic Authentication, which is what that cURLl Option does. Base64 Encoding is just a part of Basic Authentication.

Comment: Thank you so much for providing this solution!

Comment: I have tried this copy past - changed to my credentials and it doesnt work .. I get this string(173) "�<̱ 1��W ����t�����X�pl�ڤB������|����ͪZfk�1�uJ��_)���dC�-!�S�l��.���Zs�/1��ڭ�%��{�_��n$B��"ib���3uX�{�V�⫡( �Y�����<�O �M7����,��" Mailchimp executed

Comment: I have used the code provided but still no luck, I always get a "Resource Not Found" error. Anyone could make this work?

Comment: Hi There, I know this is an old thread but I'm trying to implement something similar using the v3 API. I'm an absolute newbie to using curl - could you perhaps post the rest of your code so I can see where this sits - thanks so much

Comment: No need for `$data['apikey]`, the Authorization header is enough (you can also use `CURLOPT_USERPWD` option to simplify things – it does the base64 encoding for you.)

Comment: If anyone is having trouble getting @VenomRush code to work as-is, the data center (indicated by us2 in the CURLOPT_URL line) may need to be adjusted for your account. You can get your account's data center by looking at the last part of your API key. More info: http://developer.mailchimp.com/documentation/mailchimp/guides/get-started-with-mailchimp-api-3/#resources

Answer (score 9):

These are good answers but detached from a full answer as to how you would get a form to send data and handle that response. This will demonstrate how to add a member to a list with v3.0 of the API from an HTML page via jquery `.ajax()`.

In Mailchimp:

1. Acquire your [API Key](http://kb.mailchimp.com/integrations/api-integrations/about-api-keys) and [List ID](http://kb.mailchimp.com/lists/manage-contacts/find-your-list-id)
2. Make sure you setup your list and what custom fields you want to use with it. In this case, I've set up `zipcode` as a custom field in the list BEFORE I did the API call.
3. Check out the [API docs](https://developer.mailchimp.com/documentation/mailchimp/reference/lists/members/) on adding members to lists. We are using the `create` method which requires the use of HTTP `POST` requests. There are other options in here that require `PUT` if you want to be able to modify/delete subs.

HTML:

```
<form id="pfb-signup-submission" method="post">
  <div class="sign-up-group">
    <input type="text" name="pfb-signup" id="pfb-signup-box-fname" class="pfb-signup-box" placeholder="First Name">
    <input type="text" name="pfb-signup" id="pfb-signup-box-lname" class="pfb-signup-box" placeholder="Last Name">
    <input type="email" name="pfb-signup" id="pfb-signup-box-email" class="pfb-signup-box" placeholder="youremail@example.com">
    <input type="text" name="pfb-signup" id="pfb-signup-box-zip" class="pfb-signup-box" placeholder="Zip Code">
  </div>
  <input type="submit" class="submit-button" value="Sign-up" id="pfb-signup-button"></a>
  <div id="pfb-signup-result"></div>
</form>
```

Key things:

1. Give your `<form>` a unique ID and don't forget the `method="post"` attribute so the form works.
2. Note the last line `#signup-result` is where you will deposit the feedback from the PHP script.

PHP:

```
<?php
  /*
   * Add a 'member' to a 'list' via mailchimp API v3.x
   * @ http://developer.mailchimp.com/documentation/mailchimp/reference/lists/members/#create-post_lists_list_id_members
   *
   * ================
   * BACKGROUND
   * Typical use case is that this code would get run by an .ajax() jQuery call or possibly a form action
   * The live data you need will get transferred via the global $_POST variable
   * That data must be put into an array with keys that match the mailchimp endpoints, check the above link for those
   * You also need to include your API key and list ID for this to work.
   * You'll just have to go get those and type them in here, see README.md
   * ================
   */

  // Set API Key and list ID to add a subscriber
  $api_key = 'your-api-key-here';
  $list_id = 'your-list-id-here';

  /* ================
   * DESTINATION URL
   * Note: your API URL has a location subdomain at the front of the URL string
   * It can vary depending on where you are in the world
   * To determine yours, check the last 3 digits of your API key
   * ================
   */
  $url = 'https://us5.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/lists/' . $list_id . '/members/';

  /* ================
   * DATA SETUP
   * Encode data into a format that the add subscriber mailchimp end point is looking for
   * Must include 'email_address' and 'status'
   * Statuses: pending = they get an email; subscribed = they don't get an email
   * Custom fields go into the 'merge_fields' as another array
   * More here: http://developer.mailchimp.com/documentation/mailchimp/reference/lists/members/#create-post_lists_list_id_members
   * ================
   */
  $pfb_data = array(
    'email_address' => $_POST['emailname'],
    'status'        => 'pending',
    'merge_fields'  => array(
      'FNAME'       => $_POST['firstname'],
      'LNAME'       => $_POST['lastname'],
      'ZIPCODE'     => $_POST['zipcode']
    ),
  );

  // Encode the data
  $encoded_pfb_data = json_encode($pfb_data);

  // Setup cURL sequence
  $ch = curl_init();

  /* ================
   * cURL OPTIONS
   * The tricky one here is the _USERPWD - this is how you transfer the API key over
   * _RETURNTRANSFER allows us to get the response into a variable which is nice
   * This example just POSTs, we don't edit/modify - just a simple add to a list
   * _POSTFIELDS does the heavy lifting
   * _SSL_VERIFYPEER should probably be set but I didn't do it here
   * ================
   */
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, 'user:' . $api_key);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json'));
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $encoded_pfb_data);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

  $results = curl_exec($ch); // store response
  $response = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE); // get HTTP CODE
  $errors = curl_error($ch); // store errors

  curl_close($ch);

  // Returns info back to jQuery .ajax or just outputs onto the page

  $results = array(
    'results' => $result_info,
    'response' => $response,
    'errors' => $errors
  );

  // Sends data back to the page OR the ajax() in your JS
  echo json_encode($results);
?>
```

Key things:

1. `CURLOPT_USERPWD` handles the API key and Mailchimp doesn't really show you how to do this.
2. `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER` gives us the response in such a way that we can send it back into the HTML page with the `.ajax()` `success` handler.
3. Use `json_encode`on the data you received.

JS:

```
// Signup form submission
$('#pfb-signup-submission').submit(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();

  // Get data from form and store it
  var pfbSignupFNAME = $('#pfb-signup-box-fname').val();
  var pfbSignupLNAME = $('#pfb-signup-box-lname').val();
  var pfbSignupEMAIL = $('#pfb-signup-box-email').val();
  var pfbSignupZIP = $('#pfb-signup-box-zip').val();

  // Create JSON variable of retreived data
  var pfbSignupData = {
    'firstname': pfbSignupFNAME,
    'lastname': pfbSignupLNAME,
    'email': pfbSignupEMAIL,
    'zipcode': pfbSignupZIP
  };

  // Send data to PHP script via .ajax() of jQuery
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    url: 'mailchimp-signup.php',
    data: pfbSignupData,
    success: function (results) {
      $('#pfb-signup-box-fname').hide();
      $('#pfb-signup-box-lname').hide();
      $('#pfb-signup-box-email').hide();
      $('#pfb-signup-box-zip').hide();
      $('#pfb-signup-result').text('Thanks for adding yourself to the email list. We will be in touch.');
      console.log(results);
    },
    error: function (results) {
      $('#pfb-signup-result').html('<p>Sorry but we were unable to add you into the email list.</p>');
      console.log(results);
    }
  });
});
```

Key things:

1. `JSON` data is VERY touchy on transfer. Here, I am putting it into an array and it looks easy. If you are having problems, it is likely because of how your JSON data is structured. Check this out!
2. The keys for your JSON data will become what you reference in the PHP `_POST` global variable. In this case it will be `_POST['email']`, `_POST['firstname']`, etc. But you could name them whatever you want - just remember what you name the keys of the `data` part of your JSON transfer is how you access them in PHP.
3. This obviously requires jQuery ;)

Comment: Hello Mate, I followed your code examples and I couldn't get it to work for my project. Do you mind if we connect so I get some help from you? thanks!

Comment: make a gist and I'll check it out.

Answer (score 3):

**BATCH LOAD** - OK, so after having my previous reply deleted for just using links I have updated with the code I managed to get working. Appreciate anyone to simplify / correct / refine / put in function etc as I'm still learning this stuff, but I got batch member list add working :)

```
$apikey = "whatever-us99";                            
$list_id = "12ab34dc56";

$email1 = "jack@email.com";
$fname1 = "Jack";
$lname1 = "Black";

$email2 = "jill@email.com";
$fname2 = "Jill";
$lname2 = "Hill";

$auth = base64_encode( 'user:'.$apikey );

$data1 = array(
    "apikey"        => $apikey,
    "email_address" => $email1,
    "status"        => "subscribed",
    "merge_fields"  => array(                
            'FNAME' => $fname1,
            'LNAME' => $lname1,
    )
);

$data2 = array(
    "apikey"        => $apikey,
    "email_address" => $email2,
    "status"        => "subscribed",                
    "merge_fields"  => array(                
            'FNAME' => $fname2,
            'LNAME' => $lname2,
    )
);

$json_data1 = json_encode($data1);
$json_data2 = json_encode($data2);

$array = array(
    "operations" => array(
        array(
            "method" => "POST",
            "path" => "/lists/$list_id/members/",
            "body" => $json_data1
        ),
        array(
            "method" => "POST",
            "path" => "/lists/$list_id/members/",
            "body" => $json_data2
        )
    )
);

$json_post = json_encode($array);

$ch = curl_init();

$curlopt_url = "https://us99.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/batches";
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $curlopt_url);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json',
'Authorization: Basic '.$auth));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'PHP-MCAPI/3.0');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $json_post);

print_r($json_post . "\n");
$result = curl_exec($ch);

var_dump($result . "\n");
print_r ($result . "\n");
```

Answer (score 1):

If it helps anyone, here is what I got working in Python using the Python *Requests* library instead of *CURL*.

As explained by @staypuftman above, you will need your API Key and List ID from MailChimp and make sure your API Key suffix and URL prefix (i.e. us5) match.

Python:

```
#########################################################################################
# To add a single contact to MailChimp (using MailChimp v3.0 API), requires:
#   + MailChimp API Key
#   + MailChimp List Id for specific list
#   + MailChimp API URL for adding a single new contact
#
# Note: the API URL has a 3/4 character location subdomain at the front of the URL string. 
# It can vary depending on where you are in the world. To determine yours, check the last 
# 3/4 characters of your API key. The API URL location subdomain must match API Key 
# suffix e.g. us5, us13, us19 etc. but in this example, us5.
# (suggest you put the following 3 values in 'settings' or 'secrets' file)
#########################################################################################
MAILCHIMP_API_KEY = 'your-api-key-here-us5'
MAILCHIMP_LIST_ID = 'your-list-id-here'
MAILCHIMP_ADD_CONTACT_TO_LIST_URL = 'https://us5.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/lists/' + MAILCHIMP_LIST_ID + '/members/'

    # Create new contact data and convert into JSON as this is what MailChimp expects in the API
    # I've hardcoded some test data but use what you get from your form as appropriate
    new_contact_data_dict = {
        "email_address": "test@testing.com",              # 'email_address' is a mandatory field
        "status": "subscribed",                           # 'status' is a mandatory field
        "merge_fields": {                                 # 'merge_fields' are optional:
            "FNAME": "John",                  
            "LNAME": "Smith"
        }
    }
    new_contact_data_json = json.dumps(new_contact_data_dict)

    # Create the new contact using MailChimp API using Python 'Requests' library
    req = requests.post(
        MAILCHIMP_ADD_CONTACT_TO_LIST_URL,
        data=new_contact_data_json,
        auth=('user', MAILCHIMP_API_KEY),
        headers={"content-type": "application/json"}
    )

    # debug info if required - .text and .json also list the 'merge_fields' names for use in contact JSON above
    # print req.status_code
    # print req.text
    # print req.json()

    if req.status_code == 200:
        # success - do anything you need to do
    else:
        # fail - do anything you need to do - but here is a useful debug message
        mailchimp_fail = 'MailChimp call failed calling this URL: {0}\n' \
                         'Returned this HTTP status code: {1}\n' \
                         'Returned this response text: {2}' \
                         .format(req.url, str(req.status_code), req.text)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you Want to run ***Batch Subscribe on a List using Mailchimp API*** . Then you can use the below function.

```
    /**
     * Mailchimp API- List Batch Subscribe added function
     *
     * @param array  $data   Passed you data as an array format.
     * @param string $apikey your mailchimp api key.
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    function batchSubscribe(array $data, $apikey)
    {
        $auth          = base64_encode('user:' . $apikey);
        $json_postData = json_encode($data);
        $ch            = curl_init();
        $dataCenter    = substr($apikey, strpos($apikey, '-') + 1);
        $curlopt_url   = 'https://' . $dataCenter . '.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/batches/';
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $curlopt_url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json',
            'Authorization: Basic ' . $auth));
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'PHP-MCAPI/3.0');
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $json_postData);
        $result = curl_exec($ch);
        return $result;
    }
```

Function Use And Data format for **Batch Operations**:

```
<?php
$apikey  = 'Your MailChimp Api Key';
$list_id = 'Your list ID';
$servername = 'localhost';
$username   = 'Youre DB username';
$password   = 'Your DB password';
$dbname     = 'Your DB Name';
// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die('Connection failed: ' . $conn->connect_error);
}
$sql       = 'SELECT * FROM emails';// your SQL Query goes here
$result    = $conn->query($sql);
$finalData = [];
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $individulData = array(
            'apikey'        => $apikey,
            'email_address' => $row['email'],
            'status'        => 'subscribed',
            'merge_fields'  => array(
                'FNAME' => 'eastwest',
                'LNAME' => 'rehab',
            )
        );
        $json_individulData        = json_encode($individulData);
        $finalData['operations'][] =
            array(
                "method" => "POST",
                "path"   => "/lists/$list_id/members/",
                "body"   => $json_individulData
            );
    }
}
$api_response = batchSubscribe($finalData, $apikey);
print_r($api_response);
$conn->close();
```

Also, You can found this code in my Github gist. [GithubGist Link](https://gist.github.com/faisalim048/fa4667ce93caeb35d36fa538906eb57f)

Reference Documentation: [Official](http://developer.mailchimp.com/documentation/mailchimp/guides/how-to-use-batch-operations/)